# How to get *-input number, currency and percent similiar to gold-* polymer elements behaviour?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

I would like a component or behaviour like gold* polymer elements (https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=gold-elements) for input of the types number, currency and percent.

Where we will get mask and validation.

Output example:

- Number >>> 999.999.999,99
- Currency >>> R$ 999.999.999,99
- Percent >>>    99,99%

Is there an easy way to do this (extends gold* or regex/pattern)?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer 1.0 elements can't be extended, but you can use one of the gold-input elements (like gold-cc-input, gold-phone-input, gold-zip-input and gold-cc-expiration as template and customize it to your needs.
It's not very hard to translate JS Polymer code to Dart.
The gold-zip-input is only a few lines of code: https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-zip-input/blob/master/gold-zip-input.html

Comment: I understood. I believe that is a way. But I would like a solution dart, I does not program in javascript.

Comment: It's not too hard to figure out what the JS code does. Just rebuild a similar element in Dart. If you're stuck, please post another more concrete question.